# Update date based off of completion date

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a fleet management system for our mechanic to track services to be performed on vehicles.

In A1, A2, A3 I have the table headers of Due Date, Service Needed, and Completed Date.

As an example it says 8/10/2018 Oil Change 8/13/2018 which correspond to the table headers appropriately.

I need code that, when the completion date is entered, automatically creates another line in the table and input the oil change but the due date will now be 3 months out from the completion date.

Comment: The 'trouble' you are experiencing 'writing some VBA' seems to be either that you have not written any or that you failed to include your own effort in your question. *'I need a VBA code...'* is not a programming question.

Comment: @Jeeped ... *mic drop*

Comment: @Jeeped I currently do not have any written. I have done tons of browsing and cannot find something that would sufficiently do what I am trying to have happen. I do not need a full out functional code for someone to write. I am asking for thoughts and help on what procedures others would take to accomplish this same situation.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to respond to when certain data is entered into specific ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to write code for vba tables as I've never done it before, but I typed up a quick macro that maybe can get you started in the right direction. From my understanding, you have three headers in A1, A2, A3, and wanted a new row inserted based on the value in B3. This new value would be the date in B3 but three months in the future.

```
Sub threeMonths()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim lrow As Long 'last row in the sheet
Dim row As Long '

Dim newDate As Date 'var to save the new date

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

With ws

    For row = 3 To (2 * lrow) Step 4 'starts at three because that's the first date, doubling the amount of rows, skip forward 4

        If .Cells(row, 1).Value <> 0 Then

            newDate = DateAdd("m", 3, .Cells(row, 2).Value) 'adding three months to the date in the cell
            .Cells(row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(row + 1, 2) = newDate

        End If

    Next row

End With

End Sub
```

If you put this code in the *Worksheet_Change* as Tim William's suggested it should do run the code automatically. Hopefully, this helps a little bit!

Comment: This does have a great start for what I am looking for. I put it into the Worksheet_change as Tim suggested, however when it happens, it immediately loops and never stops adding dates downwards

Comment: When updating a sheet from within a Worksheet_change event you need to temporarily suspend event handling using `Application.EnableEvents = False` Don't forget to reset to `True` before your code exits.

Answer (score 0):

As @TimWilliams mentioned, you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to capture whenever someone enters a value in the `Completed Date` column. Since this event gives you access to the cell that was changed. you can run a check to make sure that Column C (presumably where your completed date goes) was the cell that was updated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim serviceNeeded As String, completedDate As Date
    Dim nextEmptyCell As Range

    ' avoids issues where an entire row or column is selected
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' check if the updated cell was Column C, and there's a value
        If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value <> "" Then
            ' if Target = C2, we're getting service from B2, 1 column to the left
            serviceNeeded = Target.Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Value
            completedDate = CDate(Target.Value)

            Set nextEmptyCell = Target.Offset(rowoffset:=1)
            nextEmptyCell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Value = serviceNeeded
            nextEmptyCell.Offset(columnoffset:=-2).Value = DateAdd("m", 3, completedDate)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, there are a lot of potential edge cases that this code doesn't consider: What if a user changes the `completed date` value for an earlier row? But this should be enough to get you started.

Something else to consider: You may want to consider other solutions. For example, you can set recurring tasks in Outlook that will automatically re-generate a set amount of time after the completion of the task. You could also look into using Microsoft Access (or another database solution), which will give you more options.